# Drop packets with iptables for ssh login by user root

Tags: ssh, fail2ban, root, deny

Is it possible to have iptables DROP any packets with user "root" so that the SSH daemon doesn't even have to waste cycles denying the login attempt?

I already deny root login attempts in my ssh_config.  But that still takes up resources to deny and log the attempt.  I want to DROP the packet at the firewall (aka. iptables) before it even gets sent to the daemon.

So is it possible to drop packets based on a user?

I want to avoid using solutions like fail2ban which ban an IP address.  I don't want to ban the IP address.

Comment: I'm thinking something like the iptables module "string" found here https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables

Comment: You want to ban the IP address, but you don't want to ban the IP address? You seem to have have contradicted yourself here.

Comment: No, no I didn't. I didn't say anywhere in there that I wanted to ban IP addresses.

Comment: You said you want to drop packets when a remote connection tries to ssh in as root. This is done by matching the remote IP address. Do you mean you intend to drop _only_ that packet, and not any follow-up attempts?

Comment: Packet matching can be done by many ways, protocol, source address, destination address, and others. IP address does not need to even be considered if you are matching by protocol. If you DROP all ICMP packets for example, it does not care nor evaluate the IP Address.

Comment: The point of this is not to argue; it is to figure out exactly what you are trying to do so that your question can be answered.

Comment: I think what I am asking is not possible because the login data is not sent until the  connection is established and encrypted. So the firewall will never see the login name.

Comment: By the RFC, "In addition, this protocol (SSH) is vulnerable to denial of service attacks
   because an attacker can force the server to go through the CPU and
   memory intensive tasks of connection setup and key exchange without
   authenticating.  Implementers SHOULD provide features that make this
   more difficult, for example, only allowing connections from a subset
   of clients known to have valid users."

Comment: This is not possible as documented in the SSH protocol RFC because the login data is not sent until the connection have been established and encrypted. Therefore, the firewall will never see the login name.  And thus the firewall cannot drop the packets based on what it cannot see.

Comment: A thought, if you're simply looking to reduce resources used by ssh, might be to change the port sshd listens to. Then folks trying to log in who are not privvy to the port number will not waste sshd resources. Do not confuse this with security; it's only a marginal increase in security, at best. But it stops sshd from spending resources on people who don't know the port.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as documented in the SSH protocol RFC because the login data is not sent until the connection has been established and encrypted. Therefore, the firewall will never see the login name. And thus the firewall cannot drop the packets based on what it cannot see.

Denial of Service is a known vulnerability of the SSH protocol and must be mitigated another way.